# Computing $\bigtriangledown r^m$ knowing the vector $\boldsymbol r$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, vectors

I am asked to compute $\bigtriangledown \cdot \boldsymbol r$ and $\bigtriangledown r^m$ for $m$ constant, where $\boldsymbol r =x \boldsymbol i+ y\boldsymbol j +z\boldsymbol k$ and $r= |\boldsymbol r|$.

for calculating $\bigtriangledown r^m$, is the $(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ the modulus of $\boldsymbol r$?

if so, will $r^m$ become $(x^2 +y^2+z^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}$ ?

Comment: just use chain rule

Comment: Using chain rule for which part of the question? @nonlinearism

Comment: @mnmakrets The answer to both of your questions is yes

Answer (score 1):

$$\nabla \overrightarrow{r}=\left ( \overrightarrow{i}+\overrightarrow{j} +\overrightarrow{k}\right )$$